# Bacula errors in bacula-sd.conf

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup, bacula

I'm new to Bacula and just finished an install on Ubuntu 14.04.

I have installed mySQL then Bacula. However getting the error below.

```
user@Bacula:/$ sudo bacula-dir -tc /etc/bacula-sd.conf
13-May 18:42 bacula-dir; ERROR TERMINATION at parse_conf.c:991 Config error: Keywod "WorkingDirectory" not permitted in this previous resourse.
      : line 16, col 19 of file /etc/bacula/bacula-sd.conf
   WorkingDirectory = "var/lib/bacula"
```

I looked into this however I have not made changes around here. I also looked for trailing braces and found none.

Comment: Why are you trying to use the director to test the storage daemon's config?  It's not likely to be a valid director config; use the sd to test the sd's config.

Comment: Oh, good!  I'll write it up as an answer, then; if you could accept it (by clicking the tick outline next to it) then the question will be put to bed, and won't keep floating around like a querulous albatross.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to use the director to test the storage daemon's config.  This probably won't work, as an SD's config is not generally a valid director config.  Try using the storage daemon to test its own config:

```
sudo bacula-sd -tc /etc/bacula-sd.conf
```